Как отследить загрузку всего контента у компонента Vue?
Разрабатываю игру, и хочу добавить экран загрузки, так как при медленной скорости интернета это выглядит весьма печально. Компонент появляется после нажатия кнопки, и зависит от переменной true/false, поэтому window.onload и document.readyState не работают. Через хук update() тоже не получается.
Методы по-типу window.onload, addEventListener не работают. MutationObserver тоже вряд ли подойдет

Покажите ваш вопрос кодом и поясните, что там и как делается и какой результат хотите(но видимо не можете) получить

Ситуация простая: при появлении компонента он долговато грузится (там много картинок и т.д.) Всего навсего нужно отследить момент, когда всё на странице будет загружено. Через привычные события onload и readyState этого сделать не получается
